# Different numbers from tag badge tracker and tag stats

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, badge-progress

Why don't these numbers agree?

[image: Screenshot showing 41 score from 18 answers vs. 51 score from 27 answers]

Also, while `27 + 7 = 34`, `51 + 3 ≠ 51`.

Why are all these numbers inconsistent?

Update:
It's been a week and none of them have changed, though I'm pretty sure I haven't had any score/post activity in the tag.

Comment: Blame it on caching.  That is the SO-recommended scapegoat.

Comment: @MartinJames but they've been out of sync for a while, and seem to update independently.

Comment: It could be the scripts run at different times.  The tracker may update before the tag score script runs so you basically have day old data.  Or the script could be failing again causing this mismatch.  Something is not right though.

Comment: _"`51 + 3 ≠ 51`"_ You're right, it doesn't. _However_, the number in front of the tag is your answer score in that tag. So for the purposes of the number in front of the tag, the total score on your questions doesn't matter. (That could _definitely_ be made more clear somehow.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next badge track is a network wide bug, you can check a few similar questions:

- META SE: ["Next tag badge" panel score and answers counter discrepancy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267818/next-tag-badge-panel-score-and-answers-counter-discrepancy)
- META Travel: [“Next tag badge” progress bar does not update](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/next-tag-badge-progress-bar-does-not-update)
- META Math: [Tag badge progress not updating automatically](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22960/tag-badge-progress-not-updating-automatically)

#### workaround?

Click on the gear to select which badge you want to track, and re-select the same. The votes/answers will update.

Regarding to the votes on the tag, [@Kendra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra) already explained it that only shows the answers votes and not the questions.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was wondering why my score didn't increase even though I was getting up votes. Re-selecting did the trick.