# Tag Badge Progress doesn't add up after Accounts Merge

Tags: support, tag-badges, badge-progress

I recently merged 2 accounts. In the email sent to me before the merge, it said:

> Your badges will also reset after a merge, but will be automatically re-awarded over the next 24 hours.

I presumed that this includes the `tag badges`. After the merge, everything seems to be okay. The rep is merged, the accepted answers are there. When it comes to the other badges, I wasn't expecting it to merge, since most of the badges in the other account were pretty much the same (like the [informed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/informed) tag).

What I was expecting to add up was the `tag badges` though. My other account had a progress of `8/100 score, 17/20 answers` for the bronze [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag badge, while the older account  had a progress of `50/100 score, 71/20 answers`. So I was thinking, 24 hours after the merge, it would change to `58/100 score, 88/20 answers`, but it only kept the `50/100 score, 71/20 answers` progress.

I searched around the community but no post similar to this one. I've seen incorrect tracking of badges, but not after an account merge. Is this the intended behavior after an account merge?

Comment: They don't add up most of the time anyway: [Different numbers from tag badge tracker and tag stats](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323921/476716)

Comment: Did you try the workaround described there?

Comment: I haven't seen that post before. I'll take a look at it. Thanks @OrangeDog :)

Comment: I was going to try it out. But I noticed that the tag badge tracker progress is already matching the score as seen in the tag scores. It shows `66/100 score, 96/20 answers`, while tag scores section it shows `66 by 97`, where I think the 1 point difference is because of my tagged question. So I guess the issue just solved it's own. The *re-awarded over the next 24 hours* was confusing though.

Comment: Interesting question. I didn't even know that it was possible to merge accounts.

Comment: Now that I think about my previous comment. I'm not entirely sure if it actually added up? Or may be my current account just updated it's own progress.

Comment: @Suragch : Yes, time you merged with your other account - Jon Skeet ;-)